# Proof $ f(x,y) = |x| + |y| $ has local minimum at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, absolute-value

I'm Trying in various ways but failing , As :

$ \nabla f(x,y) = 0 $ gives me:

$f_x = \frac{x}{|x|} = 0;\quad f_y = \frac{y}{|y|} = 0,$  and both cannot be solved as assuming:

$x=0 \rightarrow \frac{0}{|0|} = \mathrm{ undetermined }$ and the same goes for $y=0$.

I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Try to prove the result directly from the definition. The function is not differentiable everywhere, so the derivative would not help you anyway.

Comment: Trying to compute with $\nabla f$ when $f$ is not differentiable: likely will fail.

Comment: @Mark mind sharing how to do so directly from the definition ?

Comment: There is no need for derivatives.

Comment: @Losh_EE Show there is a neighborhood $U$ of $(0,0)$ such that $f(x,y)\geq f(0,0)$ for all $(x,y)\in U$. I'll even give a hint: you can take $U=\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: Isn't this obvious? This function is nonnegative, and can be zero if and only if both $x$ and $y$ are zero.

Comment: @MPW it’s obvious but I need to proof it , that’s why I’m asking for help

Comment: @Mark you mean show that $f(0,0^+)$ and $f(0,0^-)$ are both bigger that $f(0,0)$ ?

Comment: @Losh_EE How do you prove $|y|\ge |0|$, for non-zero $y$?

Comment: @Losh_EE I suggest to look up the definition of a local minimum. Once you understand the definition, what I wrote should be clear.

Comment: It is an immediate consequence of the facts that (1) $|0|=0$, and (2) if $z\neq 0$ then $|z| = \max\{z,-z\}>0$. That's why I said it is obvious. Indeed, $f(0,0)=0$ and if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ then either $x\neq0$ or $y\neq0$ so $f(x,y) =|x|+|y|>0 = f(0,0)$. This proves the stronger conclusion that $f$ has a global minimum at $(0,0)$. This is pretty much exactly what @emacsdrivesmenuts says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, recall that $|x| \ge 0$ for all $x$. I suspect that you are allowed to assume this, without having to prove it. Then,
$$f(x, y) = |x| + |y| \ge |x| + 0 \ge 0 + 0 = f(0, 0)$$
for all $x, y$. This proves that $f$ is a *global* minimum (not just a local minimum). That's all the proof that's necessary.

As others have pointed out in the comments, taking derivatives is a dead end. Derivatives are an extremely useful tool in finding maxima and minima, but the derivative must exist in order for us to use it. It is perfectly possible to have a function (like this one) that achieves a minimum at a sharp point (or sharp edge), in which case the derivative will not exist. In these cases, other methods, including ad-hoc proofs like the one above, are necessary to show a function has a minimum/maximum.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I appreciate the help as well!

Answer (score 3):

The absolute value is always non-negative

$$|x| = 0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow \quad x=0$$ Thus
$$f(x,y) = 0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow \quad x=y=0$$ $$f(x,y) > 0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow \quad x\neq0 \lor y\neq0$$ This means $f$ has s global minimum at $(0,0)$, thus there is also a local minimum.

Comment: Still , how did you proof that it’s a local minimum?

Comment: @Losh_EE A global minimum is always a local minimum. Have you not yet seen a proof? It should follow directly from the definition (which should not mention derivatives).

Answer (score 0):

$|x|+|y|\geq 0$ for all $(x,y)$. Then $f(x,y)\geq0 =f(0,0)$ for all $(x,y)$ and since $f(x,y)$ is clearly convex, local minimum is global minimum! We are done!!! If you are familiar with subdifferentials of convex analysis you can use them, but you cannot use differentials!

Comment: Just a wild guess on my part, but OP may not be familiar with subdifferentials of convex analysis.